# Working with ScrollView and TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview, scrollview

I have an android activity which have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` on the same activity.
However, the length of the text exceeds the screen hence I would like it to be scrollable without scrolling away the image on top.

This is what I tried but I couldn't achieve the effect I wanted.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/xdr" />

<ScrollView>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/xdr" />
</ScrollView>
```

My thinking was that putting the `TextView` into a  `ScrollView` could make the text scroll while leaving the image, which is outside the `ScrollView` intact but it seems I'm wrong.

Please how can I achieve the effect I wanted?

Comment: use weight attributes

Comment: can i suggest that you post the complete layout, as this one, not only does not compile, but also lacks critical attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/xdr" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/xdr" />


    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed scrollviews attributes. Use this xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/xdr" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/xdr"
            ></TextView>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```